# Alterar assinatura e parâmentros de algumas funções

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou criando um programa que inverte as sequências de não-vogais de uma palavra representada por uma lista simplesmente encadeada, sem cabeça e sem sentinela. Ou seja, cada nó da lista tem um campo letra. Meu trabalho é inverter as sequências de não-vogais(espaços, consoantes e pontuações) dessa lista sem modificar a lista original.

O algoritmo em si já está pronto e funcionando. Meu problema está em **como transformar as funções do tipo `LISTA*` em funções do tipo `NO*`e quais são as implicações dessa mudança.**

Typedefs:

```
// elemento da lista
typedef struct estr {
    char letra;
    struct estr *prox;
} NO;

typedef struct {
    NO *inicio;
} LISTA;
```

Funções a serem alteradas:

```
//precisa ser do tipo NO*, bem como deve receber NO*
LISTA* clonarLista(LISTA* l){
  LISTA* resp = malloc(sizeof(LISTA));

  NO *corrente = l->inicio;
  NO *anterior = NULL; //utilizar um nó anterior para ligar os vários elementos

  while(corrente){ //agora com corrente em vez de l
    NO *novo = (NO *) malloc(sizeof(NO));
    novo->letra = corrente->letra;
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if (anterior == NULL){ //se é o primeiro fica no inicio da nova lista
        resp->inicio = novo;
    }
    else { //se não é o primeiro liga o anterior a este pelo prox
        anterior->prox = corrente;
    }

    anterior = novo;
    corrente = corrente->prox;
  }

  return resp;
}

void inverter(LISTA* resp){

    NO* atual = resp->inicio;

    /*redefinir a lista para começar vazia, sendo que o ponteiro atual ainda
    aponta para os seus elementos*/
    resp->inicio = NULL;

    while (atual != NULL){ //enquanto houver nós
        NO* corrente = atual; //guardar nó corrente
        atual = atual->prox; //avançar nó atual


        corrente->prox = resp->inicio; //fazer o prox do corrente ser o 1 da lista invertida
        resp->inicio = corrente; //o inicio passa a ser este ultimo nó
    }
}

//precisa ser do tipo NO*, bem como deve receber NO*
void decodificar(LISTA* resp) {
    NO* pNv = NULL; // Primeira não-vogal encontrada.
    NO* ultNv = NULL; // Última não-vogal encontrada.

    NO* atual = resp->inicio; // Ponteiro para percorrer a lista.

    NO* anterior = NULL;

    /* Laço para percorrer toda lista. */
    while (atual != NULL) {


        /* Enquanto atual apontar para uma não-vogal. */
        if (verificaSequencia(atual)) {
            /* Salva o primeiro caso encontrado de não-vogal. */
            pNv = atual;


            /* Procura na lista o último caso de não-vogal. */
            while (atual->prox != NULL && verificaSequencia(atual->prox)) {
                atual = atual->prox;
            }

            /* Quando a próxima letra for uma vogal, então foi atingido o fim da sequência de não-vogais. */
            ultNv = atual;

            /* Se existir uma sequência de não-vogais, ou seja, pNv e ultNv não apontarem para o mesmo elemento, então a troca de posições deve ser efetuada. */
            if (pNv != ultNv) {
                /* Chama uma função recursiva para efetuar a troca de posições sem precisar criar uma nova lista. */

                NO* proximoOriginal = ultNv->prox;

                inverterNvs(pNv->prox, pNv, ultNv);

                pNv->prox = proximoOriginal;

                if (anterior == NULL){
                    resp->inicio = ultNv;
                }
                else {
                    anterior->prox = ultNv;
                }

                atual = pNv;
            }
        }

        /* Move para o próximo elemento. */
        anterior = atual;
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
}
```

O programa deve funcionar para chamadas do tipo:

```
NO* teste = null;
teste = decodificar(p);
```

**Programa completo:** https://repl.it/KrQg/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> quais são as implicações dessa mudança ?

As implicações são poucas. Na verdade grande parte das listas puras implementadas em C usam apenas a estrutura que representa o nó:

```
typedef struct estr {
    char letra;
    struct estr *prox;
} NO;
```

Ter uma estrutura que representa a lista em si facilita noutras coisas como por exemplo:

- Saber o tamanho da estrutura adicionando um campo para o tamanho à mesma
- Ter um ponteiro para a cauda da lista também, que torna a adição à cauda com um custo de O(1)
- Facilidade em alterar o nó inicial (algo que já esta a usufruir no seu código)

Uma estrutura de lista com tamanho e ponteiro para cauda seria assim:

```
typedef struct {
    NO *inicio;
    NO *fim;
    size_t tamanho;
} LISTA;
```

Como no seu caso apenas tem o ponteiro para o inicio torna-se parecido a usar o `NO` diretamente. A maior diferença vem no código que altera o nó inicial da lista.

> como transformar as funções do tipo LISTA* em funções do tipo NO* ?

Se não houverem alterações ao nó inicial a troca é direta substituindo `resp->inicio` por `inicio`. Quando existem essas alterações tem duas formas de fazer:

**Passando ponteiro para ponteiro**

Exemplificando na função `inverter`:

```
void inverter(NO** inicio){ //agora NO** inicio

    NO* atual = *inicio; //de resp->inicio para *inicio
    *inicio = NULL; //de resp->inicio para *inicio

    while (atual != NULL){
        NO* corrente = atual;
        atual = atual->prox;

        corrente->prox = resp->inicio;
        *inicio = corrente; //de resp->inicio para *inicio
    }
}
```

Repare que a função foi declarada como `void inverter(NO** inicio)` em vez de `void inverter(NO* inicio)` como tinha sugerido. Isto faz com que seja possível de alterar o ponteiro `inicio` dentro da função diretamente, através do valor apontado, com `*inicio = ...` .

As alterações resumiram-se quase a trocar `resp->inicio` por `*inicio`.

**Retornando o novo ponteiro**

Outra forma de fazer é retornar o novo `inicio` no fim da função em vez de tentar alterar o mesmo:

```
NO* inverter(NO* inicio){ //agora já não é void e sim NO*, e recebe NO* em vez de NO**

    NO* atual = inicio;
    inicio = NULL; //de resp->inicio para inicio

    while (atual != NULL){ 
        NO* corrente = atual; 
        atual = atual->prox; 

        corrente->prox = resp->inicio;
        inicio = corrente; //de resp->inicio para inicio
    }

    return inicio; //retornar o novo inicio
}
```

Nesta ultima solução é importante dizer que `inicio = NULL;` não altera o ponteiro do `main` ou outro local onde foi chamada a função, e apenas o ponteiro local da função. É por este motivo que é necessário retornar este no fim.